# Emitting a lot of signals from a worker thread freezes the main UI

Tags: c++, qt, charts, real-time, qthread

I have a worker thread (QThread) which sends data to the main UI using signals. The data is sent every 10-50 ms and I have to update several QWT charts and a table view (QTableView) on the main UI by appending the new data retrieved by those signals (it should be as real-time as possible).

The problem is that the main UI freezes after few minutes (I think that it is flooded by the signals and that makes the main UI unresponsive).

How can I resolve this problem? I was thinking about these two solutions but I am not sure if those are the best ones and how to implement them:

1. Send fewer signals and each signal contains more data instead of only one (this means that the charts are not updated real-time and I am not sure this could be accepted).
2. Block the signals on the main UI until when the QWT charts and the table are not ready to be updated (how?) (this solution may lose some data during the visualization, but it could be accepted).

How can I resolve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: When using threads, you probably want to make sure you connect your signals to your slots using a [ConnectionType](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum) of `Qt::QueuedConnection` or you may get nasty surprises.

Comment: Are you testing a release / optimized build?

Comment: Are you forcing the charts to redraw for each individual data point? If so perhaps you should send or process data points in batch.

Comment: Yes, i make a plot->replot() every time I get a new data point. I am using Qt 5.10. I'll get informer about queued connection, thank you.

Comment: Maybe you want add code to skip the replot if you last plotted less than a second ago or some similar small time interval.

Comment: I think that I am already in the queued connection case (which is the default one when the sender lives in a separate thread). Ignoring to replot could be useful, but if it is possible to find a better solution which will maintain the real-time update would be better.

Comment: You could time how long the replot takes on average. Then use this number + some percentage as the minimum interval to plot.

Comment: The best solution is probably going to come from experimentation, but I think what I would try is an intermediate thread that receives the data updates, collects them, and then issues fewer, but larger updates to the GUI thread. I don't know what the data is, but if you're sending that much that fast, I suspect each data block is small. As mentioned above, you probably need to know how much time each replot takes, and then in your intermediate thread, use that as minimum time between updates. This has the advantage that you won't lose data.